# Check Status of onClickListener Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Is it possible to check if the `onClickListener` is attached to a `View`?

As at some point I am disabling `onClickListner` for a Button in my an `Activity`by setting it to null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use `hasOnClickListeners` method.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#hasOnClickListeners()